# How do I store this array into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

below mentioned is a part of my total script and I want to store this value to MySQl

I dont know how to use implode function here!! can any one help me??

```
 $countries = array();
foreach ($my_data as $node)
{
    foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $href)
    {
        preg_match('/([0-9\.\%]+)/',$node->nodeValue, $match);
        $countries[trim($href->nodeValue)] = $match[0]; 
    }
}    

foreach ($countries as $country => $percent) echo str_replace("Â","",(strip_tags($country))) . ' - ' . str_replace("Â","",(strip_tags($percent)));
```

Answer (score 4):

See this link:
http://www.evolt.org/node/60222
All you have to do is: $serialized_country=serialize($country)
and then store the $serialized_country in your database.
And then when you retrieve the same from the database use something like:
$country=unserialize($serialized_country)

Hope that helps.... but keep in mind, if you have to retrieve this data many number of time repeatedly in your application, then you might have to bother about the overhead of serializing and unserializing the data each time.

Comment: If thats so, then an intelligent option would be to have a table in the database that has one column for each dimension of your array.

Comment: why we cant use implode function here??

Comment: You might consider using implode, but like serialize() it is not advised, because further searching and updating would have to be done by first retrieving the current value in the database, and then use unserialize or explode function and then update the values or search the values and then storing them back.  These can be a serious performance concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [serialize()](http://ca.php.net/serialize) to convert the array into a string representation before storing it and [unserialize()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) when retrieving it?

Comment: how do I use serialize() here??

Comment: To serialize the array you just need to do $country_seriaized = serialize($country);

Comment: What do you mean by that? serialize() will give you a string representation of the array that you can then store, later calling unserialize() to get the same array back. Keys and values are stored in the serialized version of the array. Or am I missing something here...